# what is the relationship between char *[] and char ** when talking about array of character pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, command-line-arguments

In command line arguments in C we can specify the arguments vector as `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`
i understand the first one which is an array of pointers to characters but what is the relationship between an array of pointers to characters and the second type which looks a pointer to pointer to character?

Comment: As a function parameter (such as `argv` to `main`), `char **` and `char*[]` are synonymous. They're both literally `char **`.

Comment: Grab a pen and a piece of paper and draw boxes and arrows... It's best to figure this out for yourself to really understand it.

Comment: i can draw an array of pointers but ```char **``` i cant

Comment: In the case of `char **argv` the array is implicit. `argv` points to the first element. That's why `char *p = ++argv;` will set `p`' to point to the second element (that is the pointer to the string that is the second command line parameter). `char *p = ++argv;` is equivalent to `char *p = argv[1];` Maybe it's just something you have to get used to and accept...

Comment: PS: that's also why `argc` is critical... It is the dimension of the array that `argv` is pointing at, regardless if one writes `main( int argc, char **argv )` or `main( int argc, char *argv[])` The two flavours are synonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` is that:

- `char *argv[]` is a array of `char *` pointers.
- `char **argv` is a pointer to another pointer which points to a `char`.

`char *argv[]` can be visualized like this:

```
p1 -> "hello"   
p2 -> "world"  
p3 -> "!"

// p1, p2 and p3 are 
// pointers to strings
// they have type char *
 _________________
 |  p1| p2 | p3  |     
 —————————————————
// argv looks like this
// it is an array of all the pointers
```

when referencing the name of the array `argv` in an expression it will yield a pointer to the first element in the array.

The type of the array name `argv` when used in an expression is `char **`. This is because:

- The array name `argv` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.
- The first element also happens to be a pointer, so `argv` is essentially a pointer to another pointer hence the type is `char **`

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters that are arrays get implicitly adjusted by the compiler into a pointer to the first item of that array.

In case of the array `char* argv[]`, it's an array of `char*` and a pointer to the first item is therefore a `char**`. Therefore it doesn't matter if you type `char* argv[]`or `char**`, they are equivalent in this specific case.

Also since the `char* []` will get adjusted to `char**`, the size of the array doesn't matter. You could write `char* argv [42]` and that would be equivalent as well.

Subjectively, `char* argv[]` could be regarded as the most correct form, since it is 1) self-documenting - we are dealing with an array - and 2) the form used in the C standard 5.1.2.2.1 (hosted systems).